# Views do not compile correctly in asp.net mvc 4 (showing raw html in some part of the pages)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I received source code from another programmer a website which was written by asp.net mvc and entity framework code first when I build the project it builds successfully and when I run the project database create itself successfully I every thing seems fine but the index page shows up there are some corruption in some part of html of the page (which was generated from view) and they do not compile correctly and part of raw html tag will be shown in the page as if it's it hasn't been completely written and closed for example I have the following code in my view :

```
 <a href="http://pakhshoghab.com/" target="_blank">
            <img src="~/Assets/Images/XTX-IMG-OGHAB-DIST.png" style="margin-top:50px;  " />
        </a>
```

but I see this when project builds and page compiles

akhshoghab.com/" target="_blank">

I reinstall my windows,sql server,visuall studio but the problem still exist

I'm really pulling my hair about this issue and the project has a very tight dead line please for god's sake give me some help

what seems to be the problem???
[image: visual example]

Comment: Weird that reinstalling windows did not help.

Comment: can you post the code for this razr page? it looks like a missing a close tag somewhere in your code

Comment: I believe @Alundrathedreamwalker may be right. Also you do not need a self closing tag ("/>") for img element. Please refer to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp and notice "In HTML the <img> tag has no end tag."

Comment: reinstalling windows or the DB has nothing to do with any of this or almost any logic error in your code .